# scrollToRow result is off for dynamic height list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf, react-virtualized

First off, let me provide a little background on my use case for react-virtualized. I am using it together with the v2.0 beta version of [react-pdf](https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-pdf) in order to build a pdf viewer that can handle displaying/rendering pdf documents with a lot of pages more efficiently. An important requirement is that the pdf viewer is fully responsive and can handle documents that have pages that possibly have differing heights.

I have managed to combine both packages (there are a couple of minor react-pdf related hickups), but there are a couple of things that don't quite work like I would expect. Most noticeably, scrolling to a specific row (i.e. page) doesn't really work too well. To give an example, if I attempt to scroll to page index 81 (approximately the middle of my 152 page test pdf) from page index 0, I end up somewhere midway between the desired page and the next page. If I attempt to scroll to the last page index (p.i. 151) I end up at the next to last page.

I am using a combination of `WindowScroller`, `AutoSizer`, `CellMeasurer` and `List` to create my viewer (I have omitted parts that don't matter directly):

```
class Viewer extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {pdf: null, scale: 1.2};
        this._cache = new CellMeasurerCache({defaultHeight: 768, fixedWidth: true});
    }

    ...

    handleResize() {
        this._cache.clearAll();     // Reset the cached measurements for all cells
    }

    updatePageIndex(index) {
        this._cache.clearAll();
        this._list.scrollToRow(index);
    }

    rowRenderer({key, index, style, parent}) {
        return (
            <CellMeasurer cache={this._cache} columnIndex={0} key={key} parent={parent} rowIndex={index}>
                {
                    ({measure}) => (
                        <div style={style}>
                            <Page
                                onLoadSuccess={measure}
                                renderTextLayer={false}
                                pdf={this.state.pdf}
                                pageNumber={index + 1}
                                scale={this.state.scale} />
                        </div>
                    )
                }
            </CellMeasurer>
        );
    }

    render() {
        ...
        <Document
            file="./some_pdf_document.pdf"
            loading={<Loader />}
            error={this.renderError()}
            onLoadSuccess={this.onDocumentLoadSuccess.bind(this)}
        >
            <WindowScroller onResize={this.handleResize.bind(this)}>
                {
                    ({height, isScrolling, onChildScroll, scrollTop}) => (
                        <AutoSizer disableHeight>
                            {
                                ({width}) => (
                                    <List
                                        autoheight
                                        height={height}
                                        width={width}
                                        isScrolling={isScrolling}
                                        onScroll={onChildScroll}
                                        scrollToAlignment="start"
                                        scrollTop={scrollTop}
                                        overscanRowCount={5}
                                        rowCount={this.state.pdf.numPages}
                                        deferredMeasurementCache={this._cache}
                                        rowHeight={this._cache.rowHeight}
                                        rowRenderer={this.rowRenderer.bind(this)}
                                        style={{outline: 'none'}}
                                        ref={ref => this._list = ref} />
                                )
                            }
                        </AutoSizer>
                    )
                }
            </WindowScroller>
        </Document>
    }

}
...
```

Is what I do in `updatePageIndex()` correct or is there still something missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I got this to work properly (i.e. scroll to the right page) was to use the `scrollToIndex` property of the `List` component. Setting that to a certain row index strangely enough does scroll to the right page.

Only problem with using `scrollToIndex` is that it doesn't allow you to scroll back up past the scroll index. My workaround is to set the index back to -1 after the scroll has completed. However, if I do this too quick, `scrollToIndex` also scrolls to the wrong row. The only way I managed to get around this is to set the index to -1 using `setTimeout()`. Very hacky, but it does the trick. I tried other ways using `componentDidUpdate()` and a promise, but none of them worked for me.

Comment: Hi @Mikey I am facing a similar issue. Do you have the code by any chance?

Comment: Not any more, sorry. In the end I ditched the whole `CellMeasurer` thing and went with a custom row height computation implementation. Maybe [this](https://github.com/michaeldzjap/react-pdf-sample) can be of help.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a misunderstanding or two above. Firstly, calling `cache.clearAll()` will erase all measurements- requiring `CellMeasurer` to recompute them all on the next render. Unless something has changed that invalidates these measurements- (which doesn't seem to be the case from your description)- then you wouldn't want to do this. This method should only be called if a measurement may be invalid due to a change like a browser width resize that might affect the height of wrapping text content, etc.

Secondly, if you *do* need to call `cache.clearAll()` then you will *also* want to call `list.recomputeRowHeights()`. `CellMeasurer` caches *measurements* (sizes) and `List` caches *positions* (offsets). This lets data be re-ordered (eg sorted) without requiring re-measurement. All that's needed after a sort is for `List` to recompute its positions.

Check out [this code snippet](https://github.com/bvaughn/tweets/blob/master/src/components/TweetList.js#L25-L42) from a [Twitter-like demo app](https://tweets.now.sh/) I built with react-virtualized for an example of how this is done.

If the above info doesn't help you resolve matters, leave a comment and a repro on CodeSandbox or similar and I'll take a look.

Comment: Yes, I do understand that the `cache.clearAll()` might be out of place when using `list.scrollToRow()`. I only put it there because it seemed that I was getting a more accurate (but still off) result. Also tried with `list.recomputeRowHeights()` after that, but that did not improve things. It would be great if you would be willing to look at a little sample project. I will set up one tomorrow. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I've set up a github repo for a sample project https://github.com/michaeldzjap/react-pdf-sample I've tried to get it running via CodeSandbox, but then the pdf fails to load for some reason. It shouldn't be hard to get it running locally though. I hope you don't mind doing it that way. Once again, thanks for your help with this.